# Running Thinking Sphinx in two applications under passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have two different rails applications running thinking_shpinx, and one seems to not be using the correct index.

I tried setting the port in the sphinx.yml but it seems to not have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matthew, had you set port in sphinx.yml on a per-environment basis?

ie:

```
development:
  port: 3312
test:
  port: 3313
production:
  port: 3312
```

Answer (score 1):

Needed to kill searchd and clear the pids in /log